# [Android][RecyclerView] Callback when row becomes visible

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using Recyclerview consider it have 100 item and I want a callback when 21st item is visible on screen.

I am able to perform this task using RecyclerView.OnScrollListener, but I want to know if there is anything more direct like some callback from recyclerview itself.
I have also used RecyclerView.RecyclerListener but it solve my purpose.

Comment: there is no *direct* way to achieve this, but you can expect the 21st item becomes visible when `onBindViewHolder` for 22nd is called (as it is preparing 1 view in advance). You also need to handle the direction of scroll this way, and the situation when the 21st is the last item in the list (there won't be 22nd item in this case)

Comment: Yep, I also think best solution.